# Printf confusion in C

Tags: c, printf

I'm a beginner to C, and I'm having some trouble formatting a simple printf function that takes two integers, `a` & `b` and prints out `a^2 + b^2 = c`, where I assign `c` to be `a*a + b*b`..

That being said, I'm not sure how the parameters of C's printf statement work, this is what I wrote:

```
printf("%i,a ^2 + (%i,b) ^2 = %i,c", a, b, c);
```

And this is what it's printing

```
3,a ^2 + (4,b) ^2 = 25,c10,a ^2 + (10,b) ^2 = 200,c
```

Which isn't too far off, I just don't know how to get rid of the ugly variables & parenthesis I have going on like (4,b)

This is what it is supposed to look like. I know I'm missing a "\n" in there somewhere also.

```
3^2 + 4^2 = 25
10^2 + 10^2 = 200
```

Answer (score 8):

```
printf("%i^2 + %i^2 = %i\n", a, b, c);
```

You don't need to put `a`, `b`, `c` in the string, because the string is used as a template where %i will be substituted with the given parameters. You just need to add them after the string, in the correct order.

Everything that does not start with `%` will be printed as it is, as in your case with letters and parenthesis.

Comment: So essentially you just put the parameters a b & c at the end so they don't LITERALLY print a b and c?

Comment: Exactly, just put them in the correct order, in the same number as %i you have.

Answer (score 4):

When you put `a` in the quotes in the first parameter, you get a literal `a`, not the value of a.

You want to do something like this:

```
printf("%i^2 + %i^2 = %i", a, b, c);
```

The `,a` notation you have doesn't work. You use `%i` as a placeholder for an integer, then pass the integer as a separate parameter.  So, in the version I wrote above, you have three placeholders, then pass in three variables as additional parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Also you can use `printf("%d^2 + %d^2 = %d", a, b, c)` for integers too. If you need to parse doubles you can use `printf("%f^2 + %f^2 = %f", a, b, c)`. I recommend that you read the book "The C Programming Language II Edition", a really good book. Chapter Seven is about Input and Output.